# Surv function input - right,left or interval censored? In R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I am at the beginning of setting up a survival analysis in R.
I took a look in this book here: https://www.powells.com/book/modeling-survival-data-9780387987842/ but struggle to properly set the data up in the first place. So this is a very basic question to survival analysis as I can not find a good example online.

I'd to understand how to incorporate the consorized data into my surv() function. I understand the inputs in surv are:

- 0 = right censored
- 1 = event
- 2 = left censored
- 3 = interval censored

**Right Censored:** The time of study ends before an event takes place (ob1)

**Left Censored:** The event has already happend before the study starts

**Event:** Typically, death or some other form of expected outcome (marked by x)

**Intervall Censored:** The observation starts at some point in the study and has an event / drops out before end of study (ob5)

**Left truncated:** Ob 3,4,5 are left truncated

To better understand what I am talking about I sketched the described types of censored data below:

"o" marks beginning of data / first occurance in data set

"x" marks event

```
Start of study                                             End of observation
ob1 o-|-----------------------------------------------------------|--------
      |                                                           |
ob2 o-|-------------------------------xo                          |
      |                                                           |
ob3   |               o-----------------------------------xo      |
      |                                                           |
ob4   |                                      o------------------x-|----------o
      |                                                           |
ob5   |            o----------------------------o                 |
      |--------------------------------------------------------------
    1999                                                         2010
```

Finally, what would i like to know:

1. Did I classify ob1- ob5 correctly?
2. How about the other types of observations?
3. How do I represent these as input for the surv function? If for example right censored is true, i.e. the study ends how does a "0" indicate so? What is the input for the time series when neither event(1) nor end of observation occur (0)? what happens at a time when "nothing" happens?
4. When and how is the interval censored data marked? 3 for beginning and end?

I can provide some sample code if needed.

Again, thank you for your help on this and valuable questions!